# Какую структуру данных выбрать для хранения условий вложенности элементов?

Tags: структуры-данных

Допустим у нас есть HTML.
Допустим есть редактор с подстветкой кода и с дополнением кода.
Редактор знает какие элементы HTML можно вкладывать друг в друга а какие нет.
Например если мы напишем в редакторе такой код

```
<span><h4>Текст</h4></span>
```

То любая современная IDE подчеркнет H4, мол он не валидно расположен.

> Собственно вопрос, в каком виде лучше хранить подобные условные
>   зависимости, что во что можно вкладывать, и что нельзя куда то
>   вкладывать?

Comment: Просто блочные элементы нельзя выкладывать в строчные

Comment: Можно за основу взять язык селекторов CSS

Comment: Вы вопрос читали?

Comment: Что такое язык CSS и что такое структура хранения данных? И каким боком потом обрабатывать эту инфомацию? Парсить CSS и далее потом работать с этой информацией в каком то языке программирования, например в VB.NET, вы о чем ))

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь значит нужно создать два списка элементов . блочных и строчных.

Comment: HTML частный случай. Речь не только про HTML и строчные/блочные элементы.

Comment: А чем текст не структура хранения данных ? тем более что вам по сути нужен сильно порезанный по функционалу css. что нибудь вроде `span h4: error`. хотя конечно вы можете просто в каком то массиве описать h4 и список элементов в которых он не может находится. А если вы о том, как надо хранить, что бы быстро найти нужную информацию, т.е. то во что этот же а-ля css превратить потом, так это зависит от того как вы разбираете входной текст, есть ли у вас например понятие контекста и как этот контекст формируется и хранится

Comment: Да я как раз о том, что надо потом как то быстро обрабатывать условия при работе с сотнями элементов. Чтобы было удобно выбирать из хранилища и быстро. А не парсить текст, поотм его перегонять в какую то структуру внутри языковую и с ней работать.

Comment: Ну по хорошему для начала можно было бы остановится на `"элемент"=>[ "контекст":результат, "контекст":результат ]` но тут вопрос на сколько сложен этот самый контекст и можно ли его описать так, что бы по нему сделать ключ

Comment: Я бы попробовал написать конечный автомат и хранил бы все в таблице.

Comment: Можно создать ассоциативный массив для элемента и набора допустимых вложенных элементов.